# How to Send a Email notification from Azure Data Factory

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have been working on a requirement to send the email notification that lists the files that is transferred to a FileShare using Azure Data Factory.

I have also been instructed not to use Logic Apps and Sendgrid and cannot use log analytics as the team wants no additional charge applied to that subscription and for other reasons.

I have been trying using AKS service or via Databricks.
Can anyone guide me the process to achieve the same, i only have the details of SMTP server and port(No credentials required). Please share any pseudocode if any

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SSIS, Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Engineering Pipelines do not have an out of the box activity to send a email.

Don't fret, you can create an logic app to send the email.  This application can be called via an web activity in the above services.  Here are the details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email

Comment: You can also create an Azure Function to send email and call that from your pipeline.

Comment: Logic Apps are Azure Functions behind the scenes.  AFAIK

Comment: Data Factory is Logic Apps behind the scenes, except DataFlows which are Spark notebooks :-) It's all one big mix, just depends on what surface area you want to expose.